# IDA Pro: How to modify a local variable value with given string?

Tags: assembly, arm, ida

I have an local variable called name is version and value is info.version, i want to replace this value with given string “5,555”
i think here is the this variable value line

```
.text:0000000000006BCC                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_B8], rdx
```

its enouhg replace [rsp+0B8h+var_B8] this with “5,555” hex ?
how can i replace this value with given string ?

full part of subroutine

```
.text:0000000000006B80 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:0000000000006B80
.text:0000000000006B80
.text:0000000000006B80                 public GetResponseAll
.text:0000000000006B80 GetResponseAll proc near         ; DATA XREF: LOAD:0000000000001108↑o
.text:0000000000006B80
.text:0000000000006B80 var_B8          = qword ptr -0B8h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_B0          = qword ptr -0B0h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_A8          = qword ptr -0A8h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_A0          = qword ptr -0A0h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_98          = byte ptr -98h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_97          = byte ptr -97h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_96          = word ptr -96h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_90          = qword ptr -90h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_88          = qword ptr -88h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_80          = qword ptr -80h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_78          = qword ptr -78h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_70          = qword ptr -70h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_68          = qword ptr -68h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_60          = qword ptr -60h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_58          = qword ptr -58h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_50          = qword ptr -50h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_48          = dword ptr -48h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_44          = dword ptr -44h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_40          = qword ptr -40h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_38          = qword ptr -38h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_30          = dword ptr -30h
.text:0000000000006B80 var_28          = qword ptr -28h
.text:0000000000006B80
.text:0000000000006B80 ; __unwind {
.text:0000000000006B80                 test    rdi, rdi
.text:0000000000006B83                 jz      loc_6D10
.text:0000000000006B89                 test    rsi, rsi
.text:0000000000006B8C                 jz      loc_6D10
.text:0000000000006B92                 push    r12
.text:0000000000006B94                 push    rbp
.text:0000000000006B95                 lea     rbp, [rdi+8]
.text:0000000000006B99                 push    rbx
.text:0000000000006B9A                 mov     rbx, rdi
.text:0000000000006B9D                 mov     r12, rsi
.text:0000000000006BA0                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006BA3                 sub     rsp, 0A0h
.text:0000000000006BAA                 call    sub_B150
.text:0000000000006BAF                 test    rax, rax
.text:0000000000006BB2                 jz      loc_6D18
.text:0000000000006BB8                 mov     rdx, [rax+8]
.text:0000000000006BBC                 mov     rcx, [rax+28h]
.text:0000000000006BC0                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006BC3                 mov     rbx, [rax+30h]
.text:0000000000006BC7                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_B0], rcx
.text:0000000000006BCC                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_B8], rdx
.text:0000000000006BD0                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_A8], rbx
.text:0000000000006BD5                 mov     rdx, [rax]
.text:0000000000006BD8                 lea     rbx, qword_22F4A0
.text:0000000000006BDF                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_A0], rdx
.text:0000000000006BE4                 movzx   edx, byte ptr [rax+38h]
.text:0000000000006BE8                 mov     rsi, [rbx]
.text:0000000000006BEB                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_98], dl
.text:0000000000006BEF                 movzx   edx, byte ptr [rax+39h]
.text:0000000000006BF3                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_97], dl
.text:0000000000006BF7                 movzx   edx, word ptr [rax+3Ah]
.text:0000000000006BFB                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_96], dx
.text:0000000000006C00                 mov     rdx, [rax+40h]
.text:0000000000006C04                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_90], rdx
.text:0000000000006C09                 mov     rdx, [rax+60h]
.text:0000000000006C0D                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_88], rdx
.text:0000000000006C12                 mov     rdx, [rax+80h]
.text:0000000000006C19                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_80], rdx
.text:0000000000006C1E                 mov     rdx, [rax+0A0h]
.text:0000000000006C25                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_78], rdx
.text:0000000000006C2A                 mov     rdx, [rax+0C0h]
.text:0000000000006C31                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_70], rdx
.text:0000000000006C36                 mov     rdx, [rax+0E0h]
.text:0000000000006C3D                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_68], rdx
.text:0000000000006C42                 mov     rdx, [rax+100h]
.text:0000000000006C49                 mov     rax, [rax+120h]
.text:0000000000006C50                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_60], rdx
.text:0000000000006C55                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_58], rax
.text:0000000000006C5A                 call    sub_AB00
.text:0000000000006C5F                 mov     rsi, [rbx]
.text:0000000000006C62                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006C65                 mov     edx, 9
.text:0000000000006C6A                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_50], rax
.text:0000000000006C6F                 call    sub_B010
.text:0000000000006C74                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_48], eax
.text:0000000000006C78                 lea     rax, qword_22F498
.text:0000000000006C7F                 mov     edx, 8
.text:0000000000006C84                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006C87                 mov     rsi, [rax]
.text:0000000000006C8A                 call    sub_B010
.text:0000000000006C8F                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_44], eax
.text:0000000000006C93                 lea     rax, unk_22F488
.text:0000000000006C9A                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006C9D                 mov     rsi, [rax]
.text:0000000000006CA0                 call    sub_AB00
.text:0000000000006CA5                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_40], rax
.text:0000000000006CAA                 lea     rax, unk_22F480
.text:0000000000006CB1                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006CB4                 mov     rsi, [rax]
.text:0000000000006CB7                 call    sub_AB00
.text:0000000000006CBC                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_38], rax
.text:0000000000006CC4                 lea     rax, unk_22F490
.text:0000000000006CCB                 mov     edx, 4
.text:0000000000006CD0                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006CD3                 mov     rsi, [rax]
.text:0000000000006CD6                 call    sub_B010
.text:0000000000006CDB                 mov     rdi, rbp
.text:0000000000006CDE                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_30], eax
.text:0000000000006CE5                 call    sub_AAD0
.text:0000000000006CEA                 mov     rdi, rsp
.text:0000000000006CED                 mov     [rsp+0B8h+var_28], rax
.text:0000000000006CF5                 call    r12
.text:0000000000006CF8                 add     rsp, 0A0h
.text:0000000000006CFF                 mov     eax, 1
.text:0000000000006D04                 pop     rbx
.text:0000000000006D05                 pop     rbp
.text:0000000000006D06                 pop     r12
.text:0000000000006D08                 retn
.text:0000000000006D08 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000006D09                 align 10h
.text:0000000000006D10
.text:0000000000006D10 loc_6D10:                               ; CODE XREF: GetResponseAll+3↑j
.text:0000000000006D10                                         ; GetResponseAll+C↑j
.text:0000000000006D10                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0000000000006D12                 retn
.text:0000000000006D12 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000006D13                 align 8
.text:0000000000006D18
.text:0000000000006D18 loc_6D18:                               ; CODE XREF: GetResponseAll+32↑j
.text:0000000000006D18                 mov     dword ptr [rbx+2A0h], 5
.text:0000000000006D22                 add     rsp, 0A0h
.text:0000000000006D29                 pop     rbx
.text:0000000000006D2A                 pop     rbp
.text:0000000000006D2B                 pop     r12
.text:0000000000006D2D                 retn
.text:0000000000006D2D ; } // starts at 6B80
.text:0000000000006D2D GetResponseAll endp
.text:0000000000006D2D
.text:0000000000006D2D ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0000000000006D2E                 align 10h
.text:0000000000006D30
```

Comment: This snippet of code stores a 64-bit register value (a pointer, possibly) in a stack-based memory location. To understand whether and how that relates to your final objective, we would need to see a lot more context.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error can u check again ?

Comment: no one ? where is the players ?